# Ubuntu 18.04.3 Bluetooth failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed (INTEL® DUAL BAND WIRELESS-AC 9560 + BLUETOOTH)

Tags: drivers, 18.04, sound, bluetooth, headphones

I'm unable to connect my Bluetooth headset Sony MDR-XB950N1. Here are some info that might help:

1. This is a Ubuntu 18.04.3 from scratch (first time I did some changes, so this time it's intact)
2. Output for: `rfkill list`

   ```
   0: hci0: Bluetooth
       Soft blocked: no
       Hard blocked: no
   1: phy0: Wireless LAN
       Soft blocked: no
       Hard blocked: no
   ```
3. Output for: `dmesg | grep Blue`

   ```
   [    3.779924] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
   [    3.779933] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
   [    3.779936] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
   [    3.779937] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
   [    3.779939] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
   [    3.927905] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware revision 0.1 build 184 week 15 2019
   [    4.085989] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
   [    4.085990] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
   [    4.085992] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
   [   51.943002] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
   [   51.943005] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
   [   51.943008] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
   [ 3337.300487] audit: type=1107 audit(1578332620.663:53): pid=714 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager" member="GetManagedObjects" mask="send" name="org.bluez" pid=5801 label="snap.teams-for-linux.teams-for-linux" peer_pid=847 peer_label="unconfined"
   ```
4. Output for: `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb`

   ```
   00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak] [8086:a370] (rev 10)
       Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0034]
       Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
   Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
   Bus 001 Device 004: ID 048d:ce00 Integrated Technology Express, Inc. 
   Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
   Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
   Bus 001 Device 006: ID 8087:0aaa Intel Corp. 
   Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04f2:b65a Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
   Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
   ```
5. Trying over `bluetoothctl`:

   ```
   [NEW] Controller 38:00:25:A1:F0:85 bonavel [default]
   Agent registered
   [bluetooth]# list
   Controller 38:00:25:A1:F0:85 bonavel [default]
   [NEW] Device 04:5D:4B:96:D5:65 MDR-XB950N1
   [bluetooth]# devices
   Device 04:5D:4B:96:D5:65 MDR-XB950N1
   [bluetooth]# scan on
   Discovery started
   [bluetooth]# devices
   Device 04:5D:4B:96:D5:65 MDR-XB950N1
   [bluetooth]# pair 04:5D:4B:96:D5:65
   Attempting to pair with 04:5D:4B:96:D5:65
   [CHG] Device 04:5D:4B:96:D5:65 Connected: yes
   [CHG] Device 04:5D:4B:96:D5:65 Connected: no
   [CHG] Device 04:5D:4B:96:D5:65 Paired: yes
   Pairing successful
   [CHG] Controller 38:00:25:A1:F0:85 Discoverable: no
   [bluetooth]# trust 04:5D:4B:96:D5:65
   [CHG] Device 04:5D:4B:96:D5:65 Trusted: yes
   Changing 04:5D:4B:96:D5:65 trust succeeded
   [bluetooth]# connect 04:5D:4B:96:D5:65
   Attempting to connect to 04:5D:4B:96:D5:65
   Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed
   [bluetooth]# 
   [CHG] Controller 38:00:25:A1:F0:85 DiscoverableTimeout: 0x00000000
   [CHG] Controller 38:00:25:A1:F0:85 DiscoverableTimeout: 0x00000000
   [CHG] Controller 38:00:25:A1:F0:85 Discoverable: yes
   [bluetooth]# devices
   Device 04:5D:4B:96:D5:65 MDR-XB950N1
   [bluetooth]# connect 04:5D:4B:96:D5:65
   Attempting to connect to 04:5D:4B:96:D5:65
   Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed
   ```
6. My Bluetooth Logitech M585 worked fine:

   ```
   Device E1:B5:43:77:D0:97 M585/M590
   ```
7. Output of `tail -f /var/log/syslog` when trying to connect again over `bluetoothctl`:

   ```
   Jan  4 16:46:43 bonavel bluetoothd[887]: 04:5D:4B:96:D5:65: error updating services: Host is down (112)
   ```
8. Output of `pactl list | grep -i bluetooth`

   ```
   Name: module-bluetooth-policy
       module.description = "Policy module to make using bluetooth devices out-of-the-box easier"
   Name: module-bluetooth-discover
       module.description = "Detect available Bluetooth daemon and load the corresponding discovery module"
       module.description = "Detect available BlueZ 5 Bluetooth audio devices and load BlueZ 5 Bluetooth audio drivers"
   ```
9. Applied [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1069401/313833) solution and it is still not working.
10. Applied [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1190826/313833) solution and now I was able to pair and connect, but it was unable to reproduce sound though it quickly disconnected.
11. Output of `bluetoothctl` after item 10.

```
    [bluetooth]# info 04:5D:4B:96:D5:65
    Device 04:5D:4B:96:D5:65 (public)
        Name: MDR-XB950N1
        Alias: MDR-XB950N1
        Class: 0x00240404
        Icon: audio-card
        Paired: yes
        Trusted: no
        Blocked: no
        Connected: no
        LegacyPairing: no
        UUID: Handsfree                 (0000111e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Headset                   (00001108-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Audio Sink                (0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Advanced Audio Distribu.. (0000110d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: A/V Remote Control        (0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: A/V Remote Control Target (0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Headset HS                (00001131-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: A/V Remote Control Cont.. (0000110f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Vendor specific           (00000000-deca-fade-deca-deafdecacaff)
        Modalias: usb:v054Cp0BEAd0102
    [bluetooth]# connect 04:5D:4B:96:D5:65
    Attempting to connect to 04:5D:4B:96:D5:65
    [CHG] Device 04:5D:4B:96:D5:65 Connected: yes
    [CHG] Device 04:5D:4B:96:D5:65 UUIDs: 00000000-deca-fade-deca-deafdecacaff
    [CHG] Device 04:5D:4B:96:D5:65 UUIDs: 00001108-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    [CHG] Device 04:5D:4B:96:D5:65 UUIDs: 0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    [CHG] Device 04:5D:4B:96:D5:65 UUIDs: 0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    [CHG] Device 04:5D:4B:96:D5:65 UUIDs: 0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    [CHG] Device 04:5D:4B:96:D5:65 UUIDs: 0000111e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    [CHG] Device 04:5D:4B:96:D5:65 UUIDs: 00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    [CHG] Device 04:5D:4B:96:D5:65 UUIDs: 7b265b0e-2232-4d45-bef4-bb8ae62f813d
    [CHG] Device 04:5D:4B:96:D5:65 UUIDs: 96cc203e-5068-46ad-b32d-e316f5e069ba
    [CHG] Device 04:5D:4B:96:D5:65 UUIDs: b9b213ce-eeab-49e4-8fd9-aa478ed1b26b
    [CHG] Device 04:5D:4B:96:D5:65 ServicesResolved: yes
    Connection successful
    [CHG] Controller 38:00:25:A1:F0:85 Discovering: yes
    [CHG] Controller 38:00:25:A1:F0:85 DiscoverableTimeout: 0x00000000
    [CHG] Controller 38:00:25:A1:F0:85 DiscoverableTimeout: 0x00000000
    [CHG] Controller 38:00:25:A1:F0:85 Discoverable: yes
    [CHG] Device 04:5D:4B:96:D5:65 ServicesResolved: no
    [CHG] Device 04:5D:4B:96:D5:65 Connected: no
    [CHG] Device 04:5D:4B:96:D5:65 Connected: yes
    [CHG] Controller 38:00:25:A1:F0:85 Discoverable: no
    [MDR-XB950N1]# connect 04:5D:4B:96:D5:65
    Attempting to connect to 04:5D:4B:96:D5:65
    Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.InProgress
```

12. I factory restored the headset following [this](https://helpguide.sony.net/mdr/xb950n1/v1/en/contents/TP0001176175.html) instructions. Then I was able to pair and connect to it. But when I put some audio through it, it feels like there was a lot of interference with only some random very cut noises that I couldn't even relate to what was being played. Then I was able to disconnected and connect again but now no sound is being played at all. Then after 1 min or so, the headset lost the connection.
13. In the software update settings this is what looks like:
    [image: software update settings]

I've been searching for more than 2 hours and applying all possible solutions I found, but none of them fixed my problem, so I reinstalled Ubuntu 18.04.3 from scratch.

Comment: Apologies because I feel this should be a comment but I do not have enough reputation. If you have WiFi/Bluetooth Intel chip (which is not completely clear to me from your info) there may be a conflict between WiFi and bluetooth Intel's integrated controllers. There is an excellent explanation [in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190815/buggy-bluetooth-connection-with-intel-wireless-ac-9560-in-ubuntu-19-10/1190826#1190826) of the causes and a solution: basically "*setting an option for* ```iwlwifi``` *kernel module that disables buggy "bluetooth coexistence" technology*". Note tha

Comment: Alf, I mentioned that answer on item 10. It didn't work. The hardware is an `INTEL® DUAL BAND WIRELESS-AC 9560 + BLUETOOTH` and I mention it on item 4.

Comment: I just discovered it's not an error only for Sony MDR-XB950N1, it also doesn't work with Google Pixel Buds 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that one of the antennas of the `Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9560` was disconnected. I've opened the computer, connected the antenna and I have a perfect working Bluetooth and an even better Wifi signal.