# Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9560 Bluetooth not working on Ubuntu. Can I create a driver?

Tags: drivers, wireless, bluetooth, intel, iwlwifi

I have a PC from a local manufacturer (Avell) that doesn't have an Ubuntu driver for the bluetooth/wireless hardware. I tried everything you can imagine and I've thoroughly described all attempts in the following post (where I still thought it was fixable): [Ubuntu 18.04.3 Bluetooth failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed (INTEL® DUAL BAND WIRELESS-AC 9560 + BLUETOOTH)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1200706/ubuntu-18-04-3-bluetooth-failed-to-connect-org-bluez-error-failed-intel-dual)

But after talking to some specialists, I've been told I need to find/write a driver for this hardware in order to have it fully functioning. I've did some research, but I didn't find any.

The hardware is `Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9560`, as you can see when I run the following command: `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb`:

```
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak] [8086:a370] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0034]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 048d:ce00 Integrated Technology Express, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 8087:0aaa Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04f2:b65a Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I have high level programming experience and I'm willing to learn myself how to write the driver, but I'm a soft Ubuntu user, never complied a driver or similar. Any help is very much appreciated.

Useful information:

1. `lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 8th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 3e9b
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Thermal Controller (rev 10)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 10)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Shared SRAM (rev 10)
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak] (rev 10)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device a368 (rev 10)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH HECI Controller (rev 10)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device a353 (rev 10)
00:1b.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port 21 (rev f0)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a335 (rev f0)
00:1e.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device a328 (rev 10)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device a30d (rev 10)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS (rev 10)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SMBus Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SPI Controller (rev 10)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1f91 (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 10fa (rev a1)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
```

2. `hciconfig -a`

```
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 38:00:25:A1:F0:85  ACL MTU: 1021:4  SCO MTU: 96:6
    UP RUNNING PSCAN 
    RX bytes:11220 acl:83 sco:0 events:784 errors:0
    TX bytes:11968 acl:84 sco:0 commands:550 errors:0
    Features: 0xbf 0xfe 0x0f 0xfe 0xdb 0xff 0x7b 0x87
    Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
    Link policy: RSWITCH SNIFF 
    Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT 
    Name: 'bonavel'
    Class: 0x1c010c
    Service Classes: Rendering, Capturing, Object Transfer
    Device Class: Computer, Laptop
    HCI Version: 5.0 (0x9)  Revision: 0x100
    LMP Version: 5.0 (0x9)  Subversion: 0x100
    Manufacturer: Intel Corp. (2)
```

3. `lsmod | grep iwlwifi`

```
iwlwifi               380928  1 iwlmvm
cfg80211              708608  3 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211
compat                 16384  4 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211,cfg80211
```

4. `dmesg | grep iwlwifi`

```
[    4.913209] Loading modules backported from iwlwifi
[    4.913210] iwlwifi-stack-public:master:8794:f51dd362
[    5.008653] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 1
[    5.008655] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 2
[    5.008656] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 3
[    5.008656] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 4
[    5.008657] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 6
[    5.008658] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 8
[    5.008658] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 9
[    5.008659] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 10
[    5.008660] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 11
[    5.008660] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 15
[    5.008661] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 16
[    5.008662] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 18
[    5.008662] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 19
[    5.008664] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    5.008665] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Found debug configuration: 0
[    5.008920] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 46.6bf1df06.0 9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    5.151023] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9560, REV=0x318
[    5.199059] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: base HW address: 38:00:25:a1:f0:81
[    5.265575] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: iwlmvm doesn't allow to disable BT Coex, check bt_coex_active module parameter
[    5.689262] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3 wlo1: renamed from wlan0
```

5. `modinfo btintel`

```
filename:       /lib/modules/5.4.0-52-generic/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/btintel.ko
firmware:       intel/ibt-12-16.ddc
firmware:       intel/ibt-12-16.sfi
firmware:       intel/ibt-11-5.ddc
firmware:       intel/ibt-11-5.sfi
license:        GPL
version:        0.1
description:    Bluetooth support for Intel devices ver 0.1
author:         Marcel Holtmann <marcel@holtmann.org>
srcversion:     8215D1011CCE561BCB94364
depends:        bluetooth
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           btintel
vermagic:       5.4.0-52-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4
```

6. `dmesg | grep Bluetooth`

```
[    4.992341] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    4.992361] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    4.992364] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    4.992366] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    4.992369] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    5.142028] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware revision 0.1 build 226 week 31 2019
[    6.053221] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    6.053222] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    6.053225] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   31.816480] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   31.816487] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   31.816492] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

7. `grep Bluetooth /var/log/syslog | grep -i -e "Firmware revision" -e "ibt"`

```
Oct 30 10:07:00 bonavel kernel: [    5.142028] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware revision 0.1 build 226 week 31 2019
```

8. The list of Intel Ubuntu drivers that suppose to work: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless.html (I downloaded the lates one `iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode`) and it still don't work. Even compiled myself from https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/iwlwifi/backport-iwlwifi.git using this answer from another source: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2400595&s=e07f65d9d61552aefd730fb74761c34c&p=13799142#post13799142 and still nothing.
9. `dmesg | grep -e wl -e iwl`

```
[    4.913209] Loading modules backported from iwlwifi
[    4.913210] iwlwifi-stack-public:master:8794:f51dd362
[    5.008653] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 1
[    5.008655] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 2
[    5.008656] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 3
[    5.008656] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 4
[    5.008657] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 6
[    5.008658] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 8
[    5.008658] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 9
[    5.008659] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 10
[    5.008660] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 11
[    5.008660] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 15
[    5.008661] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 16
[    5.008662] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 18
[    5.008662] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 19
[    5.008664] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    5.008665] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Found debug configuration: 0
[    5.008920] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 46.6bf1df06.0 9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    5.151023] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9560, REV=0x318
[    5.199059] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: base HW address: 38:00:25:a1:f0:81
[    5.265575] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: iwlmvm doesn't allow to disable BT Coex, check bt_coex_active module parameter
[    5.265767] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[    5.689262] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3 wlo1: renamed from wlan0
[   10.101236] wlo1: authenticate with 28:bd:89:da:85:bc
[   10.105630] wlo1: send auth to 28:bd:89:da:85:bc (try 1/3)
[   10.159788] wlo1: authenticated
[   10.163503] wlo1: associate with 28:bd:89:da:85:bc (try 1/3)
[   10.169867] wlo1: RX AssocResp from 28:bd:89:da:85:bc (capab=0x1031 status=0 aid=4)
[   10.172317] wlo1: associated
[   10.219109] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlo1: link becomes ready
[   10.231422] wlo1: Limiting TX power to 30 (30 - 0) dBm as advertised by 28:bd:89:da:85:bc
```

Comment: You could use [ukuu](https://github.com/teejee2008/ukuu) to install a 5.9 kernel and see if that works

Comment: Do you really think that would help? I kind of doubt. It's been a year I have this problem and none of the updates nor 20.04 fixed that for me.

Comment: The newer drivers are part of newer kernels and some involve your bluetooth device

Comment: Thanks Jeremy31. Is this ukuu safe? This is my working device. Is it reversible? Will my Ubuntu keep being able to be upgraded through software updater UI?

Comment: Jeremy31, the Intel's driver says Kernel 4.14+. So you're assuming that the problem is not on the Driver, but something on the Kernel.

Comment: The wifi and bluetooth drivers are part of the kernel. Intel is constantly making changes to the kernel source code for the iwlwifi driver.  The bluetooth is handled by btusb and btintel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that one of the antennas of the `Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9560` was disconnected. I've opened the computer and connected the antenna. Now I have a perfect working Bluetooth and an even better Wifi signal.