# WIFI keeps disconnecting every half an hour

Tags: networking, network-manager, 20.04, disconnect

I have a Lenovo thinkpad with intel wireless: Cannon Point-LP CNVi [Wireless-AC] 9560.
It worked great until I upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04.
Ever since it disconnects from the internet every half an hour.

I tried upgrading the kernel to 5.7 and than down grading to 5.3
I tried playing with the wifi power saver
I tried installing the intel suggested driver (9000 v.34) instead of the provided v.46.
I tried systemctl disable --now wpa_supplicant.service
I tried using arping in crontab
And some more stuff I found that was semirelated to my problem

I found sonething interesting in the syslog but couldn't find any help online for it:

```
NetworkManager[753]: <error> [1592273107.1148] dhcp4 (wlp0s20f3): error -113 dispatching events
NetworkManager[753]: <info>  [1592273107.1149] dhcp4 (wlp0s20f3): state changed bound -> fail
NetworkManager[753]: <info>  [1592273107.1150] device (wlp0s20f3): DHCPv4: trying to acquire a new lease within 90 seconds
NetworkManager[753]: <info>  [1592273197.5254] device (wlp0s20f3): DHCPv4: grace period expired
Jun 15 22:06:37 nachshon-thinkbook NetworkManager[753]: <info>  [1592273197.5255] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: activated -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
NetworkManager[753]: <info>  [1592273197.5269] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
NetworkManager[753]: <warn>  [1592273197.5304] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: failed for connection 'Korem'
NetworkManager[753]: <info>  [1592273197.5317] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
avahi-daemon[746]: Withdrawing address record for fe88::4284:701b:3825:61df on wlp0s20f3.
avahi-daemon[746]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp0s20f3.IPv6 with address fe80::4284:701b:3825:61df.
NetworkManager[753]: <info>  [1592273197.5327] dhcp4 (wlp0s20f3): canceled DHCP transaction
avahi-daemon[746]: Interface wlp0s20f3.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
NetworkManager[753]: <info>  [1592273197.5327] dhcp4 (wlp0s20f3): state changed fail -> done
avahi-daemon[746]: Withdrawing address record for 172.18.42.16 on wlp0s20f3.
avahi-daemon[746]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp0s20f3.IPv4 with address 172.16.42.16.
avahi-daemon[746]: Interface wlp0s20f3.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
dbus-daemon[751]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.11' (uid=0 pid=753 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon ")
systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
kernel: [ 4382.017856] wlp0s20f3: deauthenticating from f2:08:6d:0d:bf:90 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
wpa_supplicant[967]: wlp0s20f3: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=f2:08:6d:0d:bf:90 reason=3 locally_generated=1
wpa_supplicant[967]: dbus: wpa_dbus_property_changed: no property SessionLength in object /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/2
whoopsie[1444]: [22:06:37] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
whoopsie[1444]: [22:06:37] offline
NetworkManager[753]: <warn>  [1592273197.5594] sup-iface[0x556a2ced3af0,wlp0s20f3]: connection disconnected (reason -3)
NetworkManager[753]: <info>  [1592273197.5595] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
dbus-daemon[751]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
```

rfkill output:

```
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
5: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

lspci -knn output

```
Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP CNVi [Wireless-AC] [8086:9df0] (rev 30)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP CNVi [Wireless-AC] [8086:0034]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

uname -a output

```
Linux 5.3.0-050300-generic #201909152230 SMP Sun Sep 15 22:32:54 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Possibly related bug with same wifi card: [*Buggy Bluetooth connection with Intel Wireless-AC 9560 in Ubuntu 19.10*](https://askubuntu.com/q/1190815/561230).

Comment: Hi @agc thanks, Itried it, it didn't help. Anyhow, I have BT turned off and connected on the 5GHz band.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to upgrade back to Kernel 5.7. Then try to update and remove:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt autoremove
```

Then I would suggest checking for the Network Manager:

```
sudo systemctl status NetworkManager.service
```

If it is not active then:

```
sudo systemctl disable wpa_supplicant.service
sudo systemctl enable NetworkManager.service
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with Intel drivers.

The problem was fixed after upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04.1.