# Bluetooth headphone fails to connect

Tags: bluetooth, headphones

I'm running Kubuntu 18.04 on a laptop, and I have a pair of Bluetooth headphones.  When I try to direct my sound output to the headphones, every attempt to pair them to the laptop is frustrated by a "failed to connect" message.  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely due to a conflict between your Bluetooth and your WiFi.  See  [Buggy Bluetooth connection with Intel Wireless-AC 9560 in Ubuntu 19.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190815/buggy-bluetooth-connection-with-intel-wireless-ac-9560-in-ubuntu-19-10/1190826#1190826). Note that this solution is appicable to a number of different environments and circumstances. not just the ones cited.