# Connecting Bluetooth headphones suddenly doesn't work anymore

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth, bluetooth-speaker

I have a pair of Soundcore P2 Bluetooth headphones. They used to work flawlessly with my Dell Latitude Computer with Ubuntu 20.04. Yesterday, I suddenly couldn't connect them anymore. I haven't installed any updates as far as I remember.

**Problemdescription**
When I go to "Bluetooth settings" and select the device in order to connect it, it connects briefly and instantly disconnects again. The headphones usually make noises when they are connected or disconnected. However, the "Connected"-noise doesn't appear anymore now. But instead it just instantly plays the "Disconnected"-noise. I assume that the connection time is too short for the "Connected"-noise to play.

**What did I try to fix?**
First, I tried just rebooting the computer, which didn't help.
I tried to reconfigure the device by clicking "Remove Device" and then reconnecting again. This didn't change anything, either.
Then I searched for a solution and found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190815/buggy-bluetooth-connection-with-intel-wireless-ac-9560-in-ubuntu-19-10/1190826#1190826). I tried the solution suggested here and it didn't help. Since this solution suggested that the problem is related to Wifi and bluetooth operating simultaneously, I also tried to switch off the Wifi adapter and connect the headphones, which also didn't work.

Does anyone have an idea, how I might get it to work again?

Comment: I could solve the problem with the answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1172000/a2dp-sink-profile-connect-failed). Now I'm wondering if I should delete this question or keep it and answer it for other people to find the solution more easily. Any thoughts?